# DateTime.ValueOf(myString) returns date completely wrong

Tags: datetime, string

I'm not sure why this is happening.

When I run

```
System.Debug(DateTime.valueOf('2019-14-11 10:55:46 pm'));
```

in `Execute Anonymous` I'm expecting it to return the same date but in a DateTime.

However, now the date that it is returning is

`2020-02-11 15:55:46`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the month and day backwards. Try

```
System.Debug(DateTime.valueOf('2019-11-14 10:55:46 PM'));
```

**SPECS**

[image]

Notice it is counting Month 14 of 2019 which puts you in February of 2020. This might be counter intuitive and you might have expected an error saying month can't be greater than 12 but because of how parse() and valueOf() work, it just calculates based on what you pass it.

Comment: That was helpful. I was confused because I had been using a 11/6/2019 string and it appeared to be working correctly.